# Underline subsections

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I am able to make subsections italic and larger using the `titlesec` package, but there seems to be no working solution to make them underlined. Here is my current document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape}

\begin{document}
\section*{Materials and Methods}
\subsection*{Sampling}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried adding `\titlerule` but this just drew a large line above the subsection title:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape\titlerule}

\begin{document}
\section*{Materials and Methods}
\subsection*{Sampling}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\titlerule`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I edited my question to show what `\titlerule` does

Comment: It depends on what kind of document. This could be true for HTML, but not for an article destined to be printed in a journal.

Comment: @xApple Does the journal style want underlined titles?

Comment: @egreg No specific journal chosen yet. This is merely a manuscript. I was just arguing that in such formats, underlines can be used for something else than links -- such as emphasis.

Comment: @xApple In good typography underlining is not used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd like to propose a different approach, using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. The reason is the the standard `\underline` command used in the other answer doesn't support line breaks, so one could end up with undesired results for long titles, as the following example illustrates:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\large\itshape\underline}

\begin{document}
\section*{Materials and Methods}
\subsection*{Sampling and some other words just to show what might go wrong with a long title for a subsection}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `explicit` option for `titlesec`, you have easy access to the title, and the `\uline` command from the `ulem` package (for example) can be used, so that now line breaks are allowed:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{ulem}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\uline{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Materials and Methods}
\subsection*{Sampling and some other words just to show what might go wrong with a long title for a subsection}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Enough has been said in comments and in the other answer about whether or not to underline, so I will not insist on this here.

Comment: I will think about good typography and the use of underlines. Thanks for the solution !

Comment: Today I noticed that the code you suggested works, but also affects the style of the automatically generated bibliography. In particular, the journal names now get underlined similarly to the subsection titles. This happens as soon as one includes the `ulem` package. This is rather strange !

Comment: @xApple load the package with the `normalem` option, as in `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`.

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to have the line extend till the end of the page ? Edit: [it seems so](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251411/76755)

Answer (score 6):

As @egreg  has pointed out, underlining is not standardly considered good practice in typography nowadays, which is just something you many want to keep in mind. Nonetheless, I don't think that should prevent you from receiving an answer to your question. If you do in fact want to underline subsections, you can do so using the `sectsty` package. Here's an MWE:

**Update**: As @GonzaloMedina points out in the other answer, my previous answer ran into problems with long (sub)section titles that needed to break over multiple lines. The approach that uses the `sectsty` package can also be remedied by loading the `ulem` package with the optional `[normalem]` argument. (The `[normalem]` argument prevents the `ulem` package from enabling the feature of the `ulem` package that replaces italics with underlining of text that is emphasized with the `\emph` and `\em` commands.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\large\itshape\underline}

\begin{document}
\section*{Materials and Methods}
\subsection*{Sampling}
\subsection*{A very long sectional heading title that will probably have to be split over two lines}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer has a simpler syntax, but ended up being incompatible with some other package I was using in my document. I think `\usepackage{lineno}` is the culprit.

Comment: @xApple Hmm, I tried loading that package with my MWE and it worked fine (both when it was loaded before and when it was loaded after `sectsty`). If you're really interested in pursuing it, you could read section 9 of the `sectsty` [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/sectsty.pdf). That might give you some clues as to what is going on. At any rate, I'm glad you have something that is working for you. Cheers.

Comment: The two lines that prevent the document from compiling are the following: `\usepackage{lineno}` `\linenumbers`. Both placed before the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @xApple I think it's going to take someone more knowledgeable than me to figure this out. If you're interested, you should ask it as another question.

Comment: @xApple, I ended up posting a [follow up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126885/follow-up-to-underline-subsections-incompatibility-between-lineno-and-sectsty) myself, asking about the compatibility issue, as I was somewhat curious. I hope you don't mind that I went ahead and did this! :)

Comment: Awesome, we will see if some latex guru can chip in !