# Underline subsection heading

Tags: sectioning

Hi I am using latex for my dissertation and I need to make a change to conform to my school rules.

I currently use the following commands for `\subsection`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{\z@}%
                                  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

which gives me

> 4.2.3 Quasi-balanced in the System Scale

but I need to have "Quasi-balanced in the System Scale" underlined only and not the subsection number. I have search but cannot find a solution that will give me what I want, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, it's always best if you can make your code a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Also did you try searching this site? The question [Underline subsections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123572/32888) seems like it would help you.

Comment: Well by default it isn't underlined at all, so it is impossible to guess what code you're using....

Comment: How should the subsection number appear: bold, or normal weight?

Answer (score 1):

This patches the `\@sect` command and uses a conditional to check whether the first parameter of `\@sect` is `subsection`. It applies `\ul` from `soul` package then to perform the formatting. I assumed the standard class `article` for this -- it does not work with `scrartcl` etc. however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  #8%
}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{subsection}{%
    \ul{#8}%
  }{%
    #8%
  }%
}{\typeout{successful patching}}{\typeout{Nope}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\subsection{Underlined with a very very very very very very very veryvery very very veryvery very very very long}
\subsubsection{Not underlined with a very very very very very very very veryvery very very veryvery very very very long}

\end{document}
```

[image]