# \hrule underlining of subsection titles

Tags: sectioning, titles, rules

I want an underlining of my subsection titles - a horizontal line that extends the whole page width like a `\hrule`.

I tried [the answer from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/how-can-i-make-a-bold-horizontal-rule-under-each-section-title) which is to add these lines:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
```

where I have changed `\section` to `\subsection`.

But this totally messes up all my subsection titles! I already have some color put on them and this is removed. Also, their subsection numbering (i.e. `5.1`) disappears and only the section part of the numbering is displayed (i.e. `5`).

How can I make this work?
And is there a way to add this horizontal line below the title **without** overwriting existing formatting of the subsections?

---

My code structure

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    %Character set
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
...

%Setting subsection and subsubsection title color
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{163, 25, 25}
\subsectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{red}}

%Setting section title bg color
\definecolor{redbg}{RGB}{235, 214, 214}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorbox{redbg}{\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\textcolor{red}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}

%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section
Text text text
\subsection
Text text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've done something similar recently, however not with `titlesec`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233139/underline-subsection-heading/245037?s=7|4.6314#245037

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the (representation for) counter for subsections and you had the one for sections. You need `\thesubsection` instead of `\thesection` in

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
```

You can introduce the color specification in the second mandatory argument (affects number and title) or in the last mandatory argument (only affects the title). A complete example; notice that I changed the color to Red (upper-case) since red is already a standard LaTeX color:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

%Setting section title bg color
\definecolor{redbg}{RGB}{235, 214, 214}
%Setting subsection and subsubsection title color
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{163, 25, 25}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{redbg}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{Red}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}

%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{Red}}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {#1}
  [{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
Text text text
\subsection{A test subsection}
Text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a working answer to my question. Unfortunately I found out that there is an issue with a version of the `titlesec` that I am already using. I have this line in the preamble as well:

`\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`

I use it to be able to add a background to section titles. When this is on, there is **no text** in my subsection titles when I use your answer here. Only the numbering and line i correct color.

Comment: I have added the code with the package and the code lines for putting a background on the section titles to the code example in the question.

Comment: @Steeven simply add `#1` in the fifth mandatory argument in my definition of \titleformat for subsections. When I arrive home I'll update the code in my answer.

Comment: I have no clue what just happened - but that worked... Thank you very much.

Comment: @Steeven You're welcome. I've updated my answer. What happened is that when using the `explicit` option for `titlesec` the titles must be given
explicitly with `#1`.