# \titleformat* Problem

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/change-section-fonts) and trying to put underline as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251408/hrule-underlining-of-subsection-titles)

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/change-section-fonts) works alone perfectly but whenever I try to add the line

`\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\sectionfont}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]`

instead of

`\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\sectionfont}`
it says

> Missing `\begin{document}. ...ion}{\bfseries\sectionfont}{\thesubsection`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % control over title section
\usepackage{fontspec}       % change to system font
\usepackage{anyfontsize}    % changing font size any
\usepackage{graphicx}   % import figure
\usepackage{setspace}   % line gap => \setstretch
\usepackage{parskip}    % linegap => \linespread
\usepackage{gensymb}    % degree symbol
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % Text alignment
\usepackage{xcolor} % changing color
\usepackage{sectsty}    % underline section

\definecolor{Nblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont[Color=Nblack,Scale=1.34]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont[Color=Nblack,Scale=1.34]{Garton Medium}
\newfontfamily\subsubsectionfont[Color=Nblack,Scale=1.34]{Garton Medium}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\sectionfont}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\itshape\subsubsectionfont}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

or if I remove `[explicit]` and add `*` after `\titleformat` it gives

> Illegal parameter number in definition of `\ttlf@section. ...esubsection}{1em}{#1}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]`

Also, like to have First Word Big caps and others small caps

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example is incomplete -- `\documentclass` is missing, and other issues ....

Comment: Why did you edit my changes to improve your format away? :-(

Comment: oops, maybe I'm editing at the same time, sorry. and how to write code structure in block?

Comment: Hi @Runar, it's a very nice edit. How you are doing the "Missing..." part and code part? It's really looking great.

Comment: That would be a blockquote, one of the buttons above the textfield when posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `\titleformat` and `\titleformat*` is very different; the latter just takes two arguments, the former is more complex.

One rarely needs `explicit`: the last mandatory argument to `\titleformat` can end with a one-parameter macro, as in the example below.

Beware also that `titlesec` and `sectsty` are incompatible with each other. Since you need the former for its advanced features, don't load `sectsty`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}       % change to system font
\usepackage{titlesec} % control over title section

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\firstword}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {~} {#1}
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\MakeUppercase{\l_tmpa_tl}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {~}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newfontfamily\sectionfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries\scshape\sectionfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
  [{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\itshape\subsectionfont}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction and something else}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

I used fonts I have on my system (and I recommend you not to use Garton).

The `\firstword` macro splits the argument at spaces, isolates the first item, encloses it into `\MakeUppercase` and finally reinstates it for printing all items separated by spaces.

[image]

Comment: 1. It's running alone, but with not with my doc.
2. I tried to find what's wrong and got `\usepackage{sectsty}` as the culprit.
3. Thank you for your efforts.
4. I'm very new to TEX, can you pl suggest any good macro tutorial. (I didn't understand single bit of `ExplSyntax`)
5. Please elaborate the working of these:`{1em}{}`

Again thank you very much.

Comment: @Mr.EU, the stuff between `ExplSyntaxOn` and `ExplSyntaxOff` is part is using the new and experimental(but stable) syntax from LaTeX3. The same code could ofcourse be written using more accoustomed latex-macros, possibly using `xstring`. Ill have a look at it later today, when I get to a computer. Regarding `{1em}{}`, the manual for `titlesec` explains it really well.