# sectsty underline and titlecap not working together

Tags: sectioning, underline, textcase

So I'm trying to make the format of the subsection be normal font size, underlined, and have title case. Below is an example, stolen from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123572/underline-subsections):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Used for section formatting
\usepackage{titlecaps} % used for title case

\sectionfont{\centering\bfseries\normalsize\titlecap}

\begin{document}
\section*{Materials and methods}

\subsectionfont{\normalfont\normalsize\underline\titlecap}
\subsection*{Sampling about something magic}

\subsectionfont{\normalfont\normalsize\titlecap}
\subsection*{A very long sectional heading title that will probably have to be split over two lines}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Output]

As you can see, the section `Sampling about something magic` makes has the underline, but not the title case. The next section with a long title has the title case once you remove the underline. How do I get both at the same time?

Also, more random note, if the `\titlecap` isn't at the end of the format arguments, it will not compile. Not sure if that helps out or not.

Comment: only the last command can have argument. So you need to define your own command as `\underline{\titlecap{#1}}`

Comment: `\subsectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont\underline{\titlecap{#1}}}` didn't work either. It looks like it's complaining about the fact that I'm using a `#1`without it actually having a command. Is there a way to do what you're talking about in the context of `\subsectionfont`?

Comment: No, you have to define new command `\UlCap` in some way like `\underline{\titlecap{#1}}` and then use it in `\subsectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont\UlCap}`.

Comment: `\newcommand{\ULcap}[1]{\underline{\titlecap{#1}}}` and `\subsectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont\ULcap}`doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Not with `sectsty` nor `titlecap`, but with `xparse` and `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec} % Used for section formatting
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\titlecap}{m}
 {
  \berggeist_titlecap:Nn \tl_use:N { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \berggeist_uline:n { \uline { #1 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \berggeist_uline:n { V }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ultitlecap}{m}
 {
  \berggeist_titlecap:Nn \berggeist_uline:V { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtitlecapexceptions}{m}
 {
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_berggeist_titlecap_exceptions_clist { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__berggeist_titlecap_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_seq
\tl_new:N \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_tl
\clist_new:N \g_berggeist_titlecap_exceptions_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \berggeist_titlecap:Nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__berggeist_titlecap_in_seq { ~ } { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__berggeist_titlecap_in_seq
   {
    \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_berggeist_titlecap_exceptions_clist { ##1 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_seq { ##1 }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nf \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_seq { \tl_mixed_case:n { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_seq { ~ }
   }
  #1 \l__berggeist_titlecap_out_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn { Nf }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addtitlecapexceptions{a,an,and,or,to}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\filcenter\bfseries\normalsize}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\titlecap}

\begin{document}

\section*{Materials and methods}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\normalsize}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {\titlecap}

\subsection*{Sampling about something magic}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\normalsize}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {\ultitlecap}

\subsection*{A very long sectional heading title that
  will probably have to be split over two lines}
Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, please, don't inflict underlining to your readers.

Comment: Thanks for the code. That's a lot of code for just making an underline...

As for the infliction of underlining, that is done by TMS proceedings format. I have no say in it unfortunately.